# CSS - Absolute positioned full width element gets cut after zooming

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

An element is positioned absolutely and is made to full width using the `left` and the `right` properties set to `0`

The problem is, when the window is zoomed, the element is made full width only to viewport. The below images explain the problem in detail

Is there any CSS hack to fix this issue.

JSfiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/vaakash/kdgJp/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
body {
position:relative;
float:left;
}

#header {
width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PNaSz/

This will make sure the `absolute` element orients against the `body` in width (because its positioned `relative`), `float:left` will make sure the body is as wide as the content.

Comment: Is there any solution so that I can achieve the same output as shown in the demo ??

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use `width: 100%;`?

Comment: hi @Natalia, you should ask questions in this comment section so your answer is not in form of a question.